# Spark replication factor for local filesystem

Tags: apache-spark, replication-factor

I am writing results of spark execution to local filesystem. Is there any way, I can provide a replication factor for the intermediary task results so that if a worker node goes down, there is no need to rerun the tasks already executed on that node?